# Trouble Understanding Xcodemath error messages

Tags: swift, xcode

I have been working to understand why I am getting the error messages shown in the attachment.

The bottom-most message that indicates a comma is needed makes no sense to me at all.

The other two messages may well be related to a problem with data types, but I cannot determine what data type rules I have violated.

Many thanks for your time and attention.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a few different errors cropping up, and the error about the separator is not really indicative of the problem.

SecondPartFraction is being declared twice. If those are meant to be two different variables, they should have two different names. If you simply wish to reassign a new value to SecondPartFraction, just drop the var off the second time you use it (as is has already been declared, you simply need to refer to it again).

Doubles and Ints can't be together for division, so that error is correct. If you want to get a Double result, just change the 16 to 16.0. Then the compiler won't complain.

The numbers you're getting are originating from a textfield too, which might cause some problems. If the user enters text into your textfields, instead of numbers, the app will crash since StepFirstPart and StepSecondPart are force unwrapped. You will probably want to do some kind of [Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) to handle the case where the entry is not numeric.

In the last line, the label text is being set to an Int - in order to do this, you'll have to use string interpolation instead, since the text for a label must be a string rather than a number:

```
TotalNumRisers.text = "\(TotalRisers)"
```

Just one last quick note - in Swift, camel casing is standard for naming, so the first letter of every variable should be lowercase, then the others upper. So StepFirstPart would become stepFirstPart instead.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was aware of camelCase and planned to clean up my code.  I did change 16 to 16.0 and the error message changed to "Binary operator '/'  cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Double'. I'm assuming this is due to the fact that my first variable declaration is "let StepFirstPart = Double(StepHgtWhole.text!)" and then the line with the error is "SecondPartFraction = (Double(StepSecondPart)) / 16.0", so somehow the optional must be the root of my problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: I also followed your suggestion to change the label to "  TotalNumRisers.text = \(TotalRisers)" but I continue to get the error "Expected '/' separator.  I will read the optional chaining link. It looks like great information.  Regards.

Comment: Yeah, the Double? part is because there's an optional. There's an extra comma at the end of the BoardLength line, that's probably causing that last error. It thinks there is going to be something after the comma.

Comment: Thanks to all for the assistance. I got everything working.

Answer (score 0):

You create the same variable twice here e.x

```
var x = 0
var x = value + x
```

instead it should be

```
var x = 0
x = value + x  // remove var from here
```